# Field homomorphism

Tags: field-theory

Theorem is

> If φ is a field homomorphism from field F to K then φ is either identical zero or injective.

I know how this come but when we say φ is identical zero then what about multiplicative identity of  F. Is it map to zero? If so then we know that multiplicative identity map to multiplicative identity then how is it possible.

Comment: Zero is (trivially) a multiplicative identity in the zero ring, but you don't have $1\neq 0$ which is often included in definitions to exclude the trivial case.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand....Is it necessary multiplicative identity map to multiplicative identity if yes that means in theorem only said about injective not about zero map.

Comment: In the zero ring (if you allow it by not insisting $1\neq 0$) there is just one possible multiplication: $0\times 0=0$, and this means that $0$ satisfies the property of being a multiplicative identity and is also its own multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you postulate field morphisms to conserve the multiplicative unit. If you do, all field morphisms are injective. If you don't, the zero morphism is permitted too.

Answer (score 0):

There are different conventions about ring (and field) homomorphisms. Some people require that the multiplicative identity is mapped to the multiplicative identity, and some don't. In this case you've clearly come across someone who doesn't recuire such a ting.

And yes, when they say that $\varphi$ is identically zero, that means, among other things, that $\varphi(1_F) = 0_K$.